# Clickable bars in bar charts if xUnits is not dc.units.ordinal

Tags: javascript, dc.js

dc.js allows clickable bar charts only for ordinal values
From dc.js:

`if (_chart.isOrdinal())
  bars.on("click", _chart.onClick);`

I tried the following and got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFiltered' of undefined at dc.js

`chart.renderlet(function(_chart){
  _chart.selectAll("rect.bar").on("click", _chart.onClick);
});`

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/168 suggests to implement custom onClick handler but I am not sure what its content should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been hearing about this error for a while, and finally tracked it down.  The advice to use `.on("click", _chart.onClick)` is generally good, but it got broken by the bar chart's version of `onClick` becoming private for some reason.  (For details, see my comment in the issue cited above.)

Two possible solutions:

1. Define your renderlet like this (hacky workaround):

   `chart.renderlet(function(_chart){
     _chart.selectAll("rect.bar").on("click", function(d) {
         _chart.onClick(d.data);
     });
   });`
2. Update to dc.js 2.0.0-beta.4, where this is fixed and the original code you posted should work.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this @Gordon. 
It is not completely fixed though. _chart.fadeDeselectedArea needs to be fixed as well. I overwrote it's definition in renderlet to apply the appropriate classes.

Comment: hmm, i guess that is the best you can do until there is full support for different filter behaviors, which will take some refactoring.  glad you got it working!